# compute $f(D)$ where $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=2x\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to compute $f(D)$ where $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=2x\}$ and $$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right).$$

Let $(u,v) \in f(D)$. I proved that if $(x,y)\in D$ is such that $(u,v)=f(x,y)$ then $(x,y)=\left(\frac{u}{u^2+v^2},\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}\right)$ and thus 
$$\left(\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}\right)^2=\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2}\implies u=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore, I proved that $f(D)\subset \left\{(u,v)\mid u=\frac{1}{2}\right\}$. Do I have to prove the other inclusion or it's already done ? And If I do have to prove the inclusion, o you have an exemple where we only have the strict inclusion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result can also be proven using [Inversive Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry). However, we will finish your approach.

You have shown that $f(D)\subset L=\left\{(u,v):u=\frac12\right\}$, but we do indeed need to show the other direction.

Suppose that $(u,v)=f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$. Then $u^2+v^2=\frac1{x^2+y^2}$ and thus,
$$
f(u,v)=(x,y)
$$
That is, $f$ is its own inverse.

Consider $(x,y)=f\left(\frac12,v\right)=\left(\frac{\frac12}{\frac14+v^2},\frac{-v}{\frac14+v^2}\right)$. It is simple to show that
$$
x^2+y^2=\frac1{\frac14+v^2}=2x
$$
That is, $f(L)\subset D\implies L=f(f(L))\subset f(D)$.

Comment: Thank you :-) (You last sentense should be $L\subset f(D)$, no ? Do you have an exemple where we don't have $L\subset f(D)$ ?

Comment: Fixed what I was trying to say. Thanks. I am not sure what you are asking; we have shown that $L=f(D)$. Are you thinking of another $f$ or another $D$?

Comment: I understood that $L=f(D)$ thank you :-) Yes I want an example of an $f$ and a $D$ such that $f(D)\subset L$ but not $L\subset f(D)$.

Comment: You only showed that $f(D)\subset L$ and you were asking if you also needed to prove that $L\subset f(D)$. The answer is "yes" and I was showing how to prove it. To get an $L$ so that $f(D)\subset L$ but $L\not\subset f(D)$, just define $L=\left\{(u,v):\left|u\right|=\frac12\right\}$